# Improved variations of the word "comicist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation

I believe the word *comicist* is a valid word (for one who is a follower of comics), but it doesn't sound right to me.

Example sentence:

> He was an accomplished comicist after decades of working in the industry.

ist definition:

> a follower of a distinctive practice, system, or philosophy, typically a political ideology or an artistic movement.

Some words sound natural with ist, such as *cartoonist* and *scientist*. But the *ist* added to comic sounds contrived.

Are there any alternatives with the same meaning? Are there rules for adding letters to *ist* to improve pronunciation?

Comment: Why do you believe *comicist* is a valid word? Did you find it in a dictionary somewhere? I've never heard it nor can I find it in any of the usual sources.

Comment: "Comicist" is apparently the name of a [magazine](https://poopsheetfoundation.com/index.php/pf-database/mini-comics/reference-materials/the-comicist-12) for people interested in comic books.  That appears to account for the bulk of Google "hits".

Comment: I thought that *comicist* would be a valid word for the same reasons *cartoonist* is a valid word.

Comment: It's not a valid word unless people use it.

Comment: Hi. You need to be clearer, because your example sentence implies that your talking about a professional (publisher? artist? collector?) but the example meaning you provided implies you're just tallking about an avid reader of comics.

Comment: I think both cases are applicable. Publisher's artist's etc. would certainly keep abreast of the industry. That said, I was thinking more of creators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comicist* from *comics* is no less valid a formation than *physicist* from *physics*, and, in fact, has been attempted before:

> Those who heard Mr. Andrews on Tuesday evening, have obtained a knowledge of the great literateur and [*comicist*](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/58887666?searchTerm=comicist) [Mark Twain] which would take weeks and months of rigorous study to accomplish … — *Broadford Courier And Reedy Creek Times* (Broadford VC), 24 July 1896.
>
> Up till now,' one of them writes, ' we did not know Puccini as a [*comicist*](https://books.google.de/books?id=hDo0AQAAMAAJ&q=%22comicist%22&dq=%22comicist%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibo8Xl75vfAhVGKlAKHSMtDXM4ChDoAQgnMAA) except in some isolated examples … — *The Musical Times* 60 (1919), 138.

Now Mark Twain is usually called a humorist and with Puccini, the word looks like a nonce creation to pair with *dramatist*. In any case, the word was not frequent enough to appear at its proper place, nestled between *comices* and *comicly* in volume 3 of the [*New English Dictionary*](https://archive.org/details/oed02arch/page/665), 1893.

This is tantamount to hanging a “vacant” sign on the word and either waiting for a new lexical tenant or letting it fade away as so many failed coinages.

A fanzine in the 1990s took up the word in the sense you envision and used it as the title:

[image]

[*Source*](https://poopsheetfoundation.com/index.php/pf-database/mini-comics/reference-materials/the-comicist-12)

For *comicist* to become a common designation for a comics author/writer/artist requires more than an ephemeral publication or a discussion on a website like this one. If, say, the late [Stan Lee_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee) had casually referred to himself a few times in public as a comicist, then all the kids who drew comics on the back of their biology notebooks would want to grow up to be one. And a word is reborn.

Comment: Nice research, thanks! Do you think *comickist* or *comixist* is any improvement over *comicist* pronunciation wise?

Comment: The specific term is *comicist*, and the broader, more familiar term, *cartoonist*. Nothing else works.

Comment: The OED has no entry for *comicist*, and I for one have never heard it used. I cannot accept your first sentence "Comicist from comics is no less valid a formation than physicist from physics,". It is, in my view less a valid formation, for the simple reason that it is not much used.

Comment: @WS2: The difference between a valid formation and a word derived through that method that actually makes it into the language has apparently escaped you. If comics artists etc. began to use the word to refer to themselves, then it would be accepted as a “proper” English word for the reason outlined.

Comment: @KarlG You are right. It has escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

The clos­est we have to or­tho­graph­ic rules that could ap­ply
here is that words end­ing in *‑c* that get end­ings that start
with *e*, *i*, or *y* must first add a *k* to pre­serve the sound.
That’s why words like *pic­nic* and *traf­fic* reg­u­lar­ly be­come
*pic­nick­er* and *traf­fick­er* re­spec­tive­ly.

So you could cer­tain­ly have a *comick­er*.

But words that take *‑ist* don’t seem to care how they’re pro­nounced,
so you wind up with *phys­ics* but *phys­i­cist*, *lyrics* but
*lyr­i­cist*. Th­ese leads you down the un­pleas­ant path from *comics* to *comi­cist*, which
I can­not blame you in the least for be­ing un­com­fort­able with. I am, too.

What­ev­er you do, your main prob­lem is go­ing to be that with­out
sup­port­ing con­text to prime your read­er, peo­ple won’t be sure
whether you are talk­ing about hu­man co­me­di­ans or about graph­ic
car­toons. This hap­pens al­ready with words like *comi­cry*, which
is am­bigu­ous in this same way: it makes you won­der whether it
is about lit­er­a­ture or the stage or the graph­ic arts.

Com­ic books have on­ly been around by that name for a smidgen more
than a cen­tu­ry, so you won’t be able to rope in old words. A
*com­i­car* is a writ­er of come­dies, while *co­mi­ces* were a
sort of Ro­man as­sem­bly, per­haps bet­ter known as *co­mi­tia*
these days if they’re men­tioned at all.

On­ly in 1913 did *com­ic artists* start to re­fer to those artists
who ac­tu­al­ly drew comics.  Then well be­fore the end of that
cen­tu­ry, at­tribu­tive use such as *com­ic col­lec­tors* no longer
raised any eye­brows.

Al­so dur­ing the lat­ter­most parts of that same cen­tu­ry did
*comix* come to mean an un­der­ground or counter‑cul­tur­al com­ic
book in­tend­ed not for chil­dren but for adults. How­ev­er, I don’t
know how wide­ly that word is known, and of course au­ral­ly
*comix­ist* is no bet­ter than *comi­cist*.

Nonethe­less, sev­er­al pos­si­bil­i­ties along that line which you
might con­sid­er are a *comix­ist* or a *comix­er*. Th­ese are not
es­tab­lished terms, but they wouldn’t con­fuse most any­one hear­ing
them.

How­ev­er, in writ­ing it might be less than scin­til­lat­ing­ly
clear whether a *comix­er* was a fan of com­ic books or some­one
who co­öper­at­ed with one or more oth­ers in some sort of mix­ing
project; that is, a *co-mix­er*.

Comment: What are the orthographic rules for adding a *t* such as in *dramatist*?

Comment: I sure that someone could locate a number of exceptions to your "rule" if they worked at it.

Comment: @HotLicks Check the OED, kid. It's THEIR.  rule. Just like *marry* but *marries*.  Just because some people can't spell doesn't stop them from getting marrryed,  eh.

Comment: @tchrist - As much as they'd like you to believe differently, OED does not make the rules.  They just document their interpretation of the rules.

Comment: @HotLicks If you have a new question, ask it. Comments that do not seek clarification are out of bounds.